# Аргументы в callback JS

Tags: javascript

Вот задачка

```
function callback (arg) {
   console.log(arg); // undefined
}



function test(callback) {
   callback(); 
}

test(callback);
```

Вопрос как передать аргументы в `callback` функцию?

Comment: какие аргументы надо передать???

Comment: `test(function() { callback(1,2,3); });`

Comment: я не понял в чем задача. На выбор: callback('defined'), callback.call(this, 'defined'), test(callback.bind(this, 'defined'))

Comment: @Grundy аргументы могут быть любые абсолютно

Comment: @modelfak я по-прежнему не понял чего Вы хотите, но кажется Вы ищете .bind

Comment: @modelfak, внутри test ничего не описано, снаружи вероятно не предполагается наличие дополнительно определенных переменных. Так что именно надо передать если у тебя ничего нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратитесь к замыканиям

```
var callback = function (a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

var wrapper = function () {
    return callback(1, 2, 3);
}

var wrapperFactory = function (a, b, c) {
    return function () {
        return callback(a, b, c);
    };
}

$element.addEventListener('click', wrapper);
$element.addEventListener('click', wrapperFactory(1, 3, 2));
```

еще лучше использовать магию с .call / .apply для передачи this

```
var factory = function (callback) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        self = this; // это скорее всего не нужно, просто я не кунг-фу мастер в js и не знаю, сохранится ли this
    return function () {
        return callback.apply(self, args);
    };
}

$element.addEventListener('click', factory(callbackA, 1, 12));
$element.addEventListener('mouseup', factory(callbackB, 'long', 'argument', 'list'));
```

@УмеренноУпоротаяУтка предлагает идентичный результат с `.bind`:

```
$element.addEventListener('click', callbackA.bind(undefined, 1, 12));
$element.addEventListener('mouseup', callbackB.bind($element, 'long', 'argument', 'list'));
```

Comment: так bind же можно и без костылефабрик, биндить можно не только контекст но и аргументы. Т.е. такая штука уже есть на уровне языка

Comment: то есть $element.addEventListener('click', callbackA.bind(window, 1, 12));

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка воу, я и не знал, пропустил как-то

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка на волнах оффтопа, partial application / каррирование не планируется в следующих релизах?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю слово "каррирование" - это оно и есть, bind возвращает функцию-обертку. Да, если что это es5 стандарт, если у вас старые ослы (<=8) или что-то еще странное, то "из коробки" нету.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка я про поддержку на уровне синтаксиса языка, пока это просто отдельный метод. каким-нибудь `var partial = plot 12 32` было бы удобней пользоваться

Comment: Про такое мне неизвестно, я впрочем почти не слежу за совсем свежими спеками

Answer (score 1):

```
//Обратитесь к аргументам данной функции.
function callback (arg) {
   console.log(callback.arguments);
}

function test(callback) {
  //Тут передаем несколько аргументов в нашу функцию 
   callback(1,2,3); 
}

test(callback);
//на выводе в консоли получаем [1,2,3]
```

Comment: ну хотя бы уж `test(callback, args)`